# Where is the right place to ask for advice about what is wrong with questions?

Tags: discussion

The last 2 questions I have asked got downvoted very quickly and I have no idea what is wrong with them.

Downvoted questions are less likely to get answers because people won't even read them.  If they don't get an answer in 30 days, they'll [get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

So, is there a place I can ask for advice on how to improve those questions?

Is it correct to as for question-specific advice here on Meta, or is there somewhere else I should ask?

I'm not asking for actual feedback here, I'm asking where I *should* ask for feedback?

I've been using SO since 2011 and I understand https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

I thought I knew what makes a good question, but it seems I'm getting it wrong, so I'd like some advice.

Comment: You only have two questions. And between those two, only one has a single downvote. The other seemed like a decent question. Do you have deleted questions?

Comment: Then of course there's the fact that the question has a comment explaining why the post is off topic.

Comment: Yes, the other question was deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348242/does-the-hash-in-a-dockerfile-comment-need-to-be-in-column-1

Comment: Yes you can ask question-specific advice here on Meta. But be careful of [the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) when doing that.

Comment: Good question are hard. And it's always cool to see one that care about it instead of ranting about elitism. I do think that after editing your deleted question you can it in a meta question, asking how you can improve it. people will review the question on the meta it self . and give you advice. You can then edit the question to your best and choose if you want to undelete it.

Comment: The [docker] tag is difficult, the tag gets pummeled by end-user questions and not enough programming questions.  Statistics are awful, only 1 in 4 questions got an answer last week, nobody earns any decent rep on answers anymore.  Usually that leads to frequent posters quitting, it is not quite there yet.  There is usually an intermediary stage where they'll try to keep the questions on topic, surely what you saw happening on those two questions.

Comment: Questions should be about software development related *problems* you are experiencing. Asking for "definitive" answers for a question that your tests gave you the true answer to is trivia at best, and isn't going to work out well on SO. Also, only the actual product owners can give you a definitive answer, so either the official docs or their official comments will suffice.

Comment: I like the first comment you got, I quote: *"I agree though that SO seems to have become the de-facto place that people post all Docker-related questions"*. Me personally, I broaden that. Stack Overflow has become the site where everyone wants to post *all* their tech-questions. I mean, there is a docker tag so all docker questions are on-topic, right? Nope. The rules are pretty clear about questions needing to be about programming problems. Your last docker question really wasn't. Me personally... I say that rule has aged, we live in a dev/ops age where the lines have blurred.

Comment: Are you asking how to improve your specific question or where to ask them? The later answer is here. Now, I would suggest that you change *this* question and ask for guidance on how to improve them instead.

Comment: @Gimby asking about the use of a programming tool for the purposes of programming isn't off-topic even if it isn't a programming question per se

Comment: I'm going to answer this question with the comment from @AndréKool since that seems to be the correct answer here. I'll then ask another question for advice on my actual SO questions.

Comment: New question about the actual SO questions... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369983/what-is-wrong-with-these-questions-how-can-i-learn-to-ask-better-questions

Answer (score 1):

As per @André Kool's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369910/where-is-the-right-place-to-ask-for-advice-about-what-is-wrong-with-questions#comment602374_369910) on the question, the answer is:

> Yes you can ask question-specific advice here on Meta. But be careful of [the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) when doing that. – André Kool