# What is wrong with these questions? How can I learn to ask better questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I previously asked this Meta question: *[Where is the right place to ask for advice about what is wrong with questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369910/46433)*

So now I'm asking for advice regarding some specific Stack Overflow questions - how can I improve them and get some answers?

I am pretty good at researching, debugging and figuring things out myself. If I reach the point where I need ask a question on Stack Overflow it means I have already exhausted every avenue I can think of and the question is by definition rather esoteric.

What additional information should I be adding to convey that I've already done a lot of research and investigations? Should I include a lot more references?

I tend to think if there's *too much* detail it will put people off, but maybe that's where I'm going wrong?

The specific questions I'm trying improve are:

#### [How to switch between Stable and Edge version of Docker on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50964595/46433)

- Should I clarify that I'm asking this question related to my development environment, therefore it's definitely programming related?
- There is widespread disagreement about whether questions like this belong on Stack Overflow or Server Fault.

  - For the purists, this is about installation of a tool which is used both in programming and non-programming, therefore it belongs on Server Fault.
  - Pragmatists say that it belongs in the place it's more likely to get an answer. The consensus for this type of Docker question is that Stack Overflow is likely to get more/better answers.

#### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348242/does-the-hash-in-a-dockerfile-comment-need-to-be-in-column-1

- This was auto-deleted. Is it worth trying to edit and resurrect it?
- I made it very clear in the question that I have done research and also tried it myself.
- The original downvoter admitted in comments that it was a mistake, but Stack Overflow doesn't allow reversal of downvotes.
- There has been some suggestion that the question is nothing more than trivia.  It's a question about the correct syntax of a programming language, surely that's exactly why Stack Overflow exists? It definitely not just trivia.
- I train lots of developers, and I want to ensure the information I'm passing on is correct.
- I did [request a clarification](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/6700) on the documentation, but I'm interested in whether people actually do use the hash in the way I'm querying.
- Should I put some example use cases in the question?
- The reason why I asked the question in the first place is due to the way [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) handles commenting of indented lines in Dockerfiles - it indents the hash symbols. I wondered whether it is doing it wrong and whether I need to not use that feature.

  - Visual Studio Code is a VERY popular editor and has strong support for editing Docker configurations. A LOT of people are using it for this purpose.

Comment: Not sure as to the second, as I'm unable to see it. I've upvoted the first.

Comment: If anyone can see the second question, please consider including a screenshot here.

Comment: IIRC, as post author, you can vote to undelete your own question. It only takes 3 votes to undelete. Both your questions look fine to me, I don't understand why that deleted question got downvoted.

Comment: You already asked this question, hard to see what is different.  SO is unlikely to be the place to get the support you want.  That is not a problem, [you can buy it](https://success.docker.com/article/commercial-support-service-levels).

Comment: @HansPassant no I haven’t. The other question was about _where_ to ask for help. This question is actually asking for help. SO is about creating useful artefacts and the other question was generic and useful to anyone. This question is only really useful to me.

Answer (score 19):

This answer is going to suck, but...

## Nothing was wrong with *either* of those questions.  Not *really*...

Let's take [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964595/how-to-switch-between-stable-and-edge-version-of-docker-on-ubuntu) for starters.  It definitely comes across as having the smell of being something that you just install on your machine as part of your server infrastructure, but Docker is a notable and explicit [gray area on the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276579/1079354).  The main thing that makes this less gray in my mind is that you're *not* talking about how to network containers across, nor how to orchestrate them; you're looking for advice on how to install two different channels.  That  sounds like something a developer *would* do, so it sounds like it'd be on topic here.

The [second, dead question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348242/does-the-hash-in-a-dockerfile-comment-need-to-be-in-column-1) suffered from a lack of your attention.  Had you added some more details (e.g. what happened when you attempted what you were asking), it'd probably wouldn't have been autodeleted.

In reality, you may have just been caught by some bad fortune in both cases.  Clean 'em up as best as you can if you feel like you need it, and keep persevering.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll have a think about whether it's worth cleaning them up